# What the difference between [FromForm] and [FromBody] in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

What the difference between [FromForm] and [FromBody] in Asp.Net Core. 
I will use one of them for post method. 
If I use FromForm, can it occur be a security problem?

Comment: Docs explain it best https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#sources

Comment: If I use FromForm, can it occur be a security problem?

Comment: That is a  **"it depends"** kind of question which is too broad to answer here.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `FromForm` attribute is for incoming data from a submitted form sent by the content type `application/x-www-url-formencoded` while the `FromBody` will parse the model the default way, which in most cases are sent by the content type `application/json`, from the request body.

For security problem , you could use `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` Attribute for post method which specifies that the class or method that this attribute is applied validates the anti-forgery token. If the anti-forgery token is not available, or if the token is invalid, the validation will fail and the action method will not execute.

The anti-forgery token found in MVC is a way to prevent cross site request forgery (CSRF) attacks. Without going into too much detail, a CSRF attack occurs when a user visits an untrusted site and enters some information that is then posted back to a site to which the user has already authenticated.

You could refer to the following link on how AntiForgeryToken() actually works:

http://blog.at-dot.net/archive/2014/05/13/mvc-what-is-html-dot-antiforgerytoken-and-how-does-it-actually-work/#targetText=The%20anti%2Dforgery%20token%20found,the%20user%20has%20already%20authenticated.

Comment: Any word of advice on what good practice should be for using one versus the other on a typical REST service interface?

Comment: I am curious of this as well. Should Restful always use FromBody since its suppose to be in the body of the request?

Answer (score 18):

**FromBody** (*ContentType: application/json*):

```
{ "user" : "conejo", "password" : "panda" }
```

**FromForm** (*ContentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded*):

```
user=conejo&password=panda
```

Take into account that to send more than one field using **FromBody** you would have to wrap them in an object. As per se, **FromForm** is not less secure than **FromBody**. Vulnerabilities mainly come from not using [HTTPS](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/x-www-form-urlencoded#:%7E:text=Security%20considerations%3A%20In%20isolation%2C%20an,the%20context%20of%20this%20type.)

Answer (score 15):

If you look in the Microsoft documentation

- [FromQuery] - Gets values from the query string.
- [FromRoute] - Gets values from route data.
- [FromForm] - Gets values from posted form fields.
- [FromBody] - Gets values from the request body.
- [FromHeader] - Gets values from HTTP headers.

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0)