# ASP.Net Core MVC FormForm method receives null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, binding

I have an application which simulates a clothing site.I try to build my C# object with the data that the user writes in the form and the products they bought on the site.The products are represented by a JSON object.I use 2 classes: one for the shopping cart and one for the product.

```
public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; }
        public string productPrice { get; set; }

        public string quantity { get; set; }
    }



public class ShoppingCart
    {
        [Key]
        public int? id { get; set; }

        public List<Product> productList { get; set; }

        public string clientName { get; set; }

        public string clientAddress { get; set; }

        public string clientMail { get; set; }
    }
```

I use a controller which has the method "Save" which uses the [FromForm] attribute.After the objects is binded from the client side I add it to my database.The problem is that I get "null" values for every property in my ShoppingCart object that is sent to the method.Moreover in my browser, the data is sent correctly to the server:
[screenshot from network tab in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/houII.png)

The controller that I use looks like this:

```
[Route("SendItems/Save")]
    [ApiController]

    public class SendItemsController : Controller
    {
        private AppDbContext _db;

      
        public SendItemsController(AppDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Consumes("application/json")]
       
        public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromForm] ShoppingCart s)
        {

           await _db.ShoppingCarts.AddAsync(s);
           await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        [HttpGet("~/ThankYou/Index")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        
    }
```

My html for the form is written like this:

```
        @model ShoppingCart


        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label id="clienId"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="id" id="idClient" type="hidden" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label id="clientProds"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="productList" id="inputProducts" type="hidden" />
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label id="clientName"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="clientName" id="inputName" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label id="clientAddress"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="clientAddress" id="inputAddress" type="text" />
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label id="clientMail"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input asp-for="clientMail" id="inputMail" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-3 offset-4">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="orderB" asp-controller="SendItems" action="Save" type="submit">ORDER</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Also another issue is that if I don't use this piece of javascript the client is not redirected anymore to the "ThankYou" page :

```
 var orderB = document.getElementById("orderB");
        orderB.addEventListener("click", function () {
          
            var inputName = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
            var inputAddress = document.getElementById("inputAddress").value;
            var inputMail = document.getElementById("inputMail").value;
            var auxArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < productsAux.length; i++) {
                if (productsAux[i]!="") {
                auxArray[i-1] = { "productName": productsAux[i].titlu, "productPrice": productsAux[i].pret, "quantity": localStorage.getItem(productsAux[i].titlu) };
                }
            }


            document.getElementById("inputProducts").value = JSON.stringify(auxArray);

            var shoppingCart = {
                productList: auxArray,
                clientName: inputName,
                clientAddress: inputAddress,
                clientMail: inputMail
            };
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(shoppingCart),
                url: "senditems/save",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                
            })
            
        })
```

Comment: The most common cause for this behaviour is client posting data that doesn't match the model structure at server. In your screen capture I see product id is missing and you're posting a token that is not the model.

Comment: @RoarS. I'm trying to learn.If you have any advice I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have a look at Resharper, I think it is a "must-have" for every .NET developer, and especially for those who are new in the trade.

Comment: @derloopkat How is that not a model-like object?If the id is null I want to add the object to my database which automatically sets an id.

Comment: You could pass null value for a property but still include that property. Another possible cause is the use of `[FromForm]` because you're not sending a form but json. Try to replace it by `[FromBody]`. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57619256/2516718).

Comment: @ballonDor If you still having trouble, comment out part of the code and try sending less fields until you isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo worked:
Cart.cshtml(You need to change the bind of `productList,and then you don't need to use ajax to pass data to controller):

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="SendItems" asp-action="Save">
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label id="clienId"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <input asp-for="id" id="idClient" type="hidden" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label id="clientProds"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">

        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.productList.Count(); i++)
        {
            <input type="hidden"  asp-for="@Model.productList[i].id" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.productList[i].productName" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.productList[i].productPrice" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.productList[i].quantity" />
        }
    </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label id="clientName"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <input asp-for="clientName" id="inputName" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label id="clientAddress"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <input asp-for="clientAddress" id="inputAddress" type="text" />
    </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label id="clientMail"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <input asp-for="clientMail" id="inputMail" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-3 offset-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="orderB"  type="submit" >ORDER</button>
    </div>
</div>
    </form>
```

Controller(SendItems):

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Save(ShoppingCart s)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        [HttpGet("~/ThankYou/Index")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Cart()
        {
            ShoppingCart s = new ShoppingCart { id = 1, clientAddress = "address", clientName = "name1", clientMail = "123@123", productList = new List<Product> { new Product { id = 1, productName = "p1", productPrice = "10", quantity = "1" }, new Product { id = 2, productName = "p12", productPrice = "12", quantity = "3" } } };
            return View(s);
        }
```

result:
[image]