# Have to upload image with registration form data using HttpClient C#

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin, .net-core, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I have .Net Core 3.1 Api end point which takes UserData as [FromForm].

I am uploading here image also, which running fine using postman. Image uploading and UserData inserting into DB.

But when I am calling HttpClint.PostAsync then its not working, while I am using MultipartFormDataContent();

**EndPoing Signtature of API:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveUser([FromForm] UserData usr) 
{}
```

**Image Upload code at Xamarin side:**

```
  private async Task UploadFileMedia()
    {
        Constant.mediaFile = null;
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        Constant.mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

        if (Constant.mediaFile is null)
            return;
    }
```

**Http Client Hit:**

```
var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent()
                    {

                    new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
                        {new StreamContent(Constant. mediaFile.GetStream()),
                            "\"file\"",
                            $"\"{Constant.mediaFile.Path}\""}
                    };
                    requestContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                    requestContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");


 var response = await client.PostAsync("api/user/save", requestContent);
```

Comment: if you can get it to work in Postman, Postman has the ability to generate the corresponding C# code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to make request with both image file(s) and json data to your ASP.NET Core API backend, you can refer to the following code snippet.

```
requestContent.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), "Prop1");
requestContent.Add(new StreamContent({your_filestream_here}), "file", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath));


var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/user/save", requestContent);
```

*`UserData` class*

```
public class UserData
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public IFormFile file { get; set; }
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have an attribute `[FromForm] UserData usr` which accepts type application/x-www-url-formencoded, but you're sending data as application/json and you need to change the binding attribute to [FromBody] you can read about the differences here

[What the difference between [FromForm] and [FromBody] in Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57616925/what-the-difference-between-fromform-and-frombody-in-asp-net-core#:%7E:text=The%20FromForm%20attribute%20is%20for,json%20%2C%20from%20the%20request%20body.)

and [official web site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0) of course