# ASP.NET Core MVC controller unable to decode form data on form submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have just started with Asp.Net and having problems trying to use jQuery to post data to my controllers.

I am using Windows 10, ASP.Net Core 6.0.15, Visual Studio 2022.

I am trying to submit a form and on the form submit the controller is not picking up the form data - does anyone know what I am missing? Thanks

Controller post method

```
[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Index(HomeViewModel homeItems)
 { ... }
```

ViewModel

```
public class HomeViewModel
 {
    public HeaderModel Header { get; set; }
    public List<ListItemModel> ListItems { get; set; }
 }
```

Post Data

```
Header.DaysBeforeBooking=&Header.Name=&Id=0&ListItemName=&ListItemDays=&__RequestVerificationToken=xxx
```

The current form submit is done through Html.BeginForm, the submit button looks like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

I have tried using jQuery to manage the post using this:

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {

});
```

HeaderModel

```
public class HeaderModel
{
   public enum Options
   {
      Immediately,
      DaysBeforeBooking,
      Name
   }
   
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Default send notification timing is required")]
   public Options? DefaultSendNotificationTiming { get; set; }

   [Range(0, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Days must be greater than zero")]
   [RequiredIf("DefaultSendNotificationTiming", Options.DaysBeforeBooking, ErrorMessage = "Days before booking required")]
   public int? DaysBeforeBooking { get; set; }

   [RequiredIf("DefaultSendNotificationTiming", Options.Name, ErrorMessage = "Name required")]
   public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

ListItemModel

```
public class ListItemModel
{
   public enum Override
   {
      DaysBeforeBooking,
      Name
   }

   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "List item name is required")]
   public string ListItemName { get; set; }

   [Range(0, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Days must be greater than zero")]
   [RequiredIf("OverrideTiming", Override.DaysBeforeBooking, ErrorMessage = "List days required")]
   public int? ListItemDays { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: " use jQuery to post data to my controllers." Could you share your jQuery code ?

Comment: Also, please show the `HeaderModel` and `ListItemModel` - and also, typically, a `POST` has a **post body** that contains the data being sent to the controller method (as JSON, typically)

Comment: @QingGuo I have updated the question with the jQuery code. I get the same result as well when I submit the form without using jQuery

Comment: " I get the same result as well when I submit the form without using jQuery"  What's the result ? What's your formdata ?  If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Comment: Did you try with [`[FromForm]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57619256/8941307)?